# Calculating a rolling max value with a variable window size, and adjusting the position according to this window size

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, rolling-computation

I'd like to make a rolling comparison of values in a dataframe column, selecting the max value of a certain window. I currently have two columns - one `Data` column with the values, and a second column, `window`, of the size of the window I wish to perform the comparison over. I have been using the rolling function like this, as below, to do this comparison with a set window size:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,14])
data = np.random.randn(10).cumsum()
w = [3,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': data, 'Window':w})

[print(df)]

       Data  Window
0 -0.602923       3
1 -1.005579       2
2 -0.703250       2
3 -1.227599       3
4 -0.683756       2
5 -0.670621       2
6 -0.997120       3
7  0.387956       2
8  0.255502       2
9 -0.152361       3

max_values = df['Data'][::-1].rolling(3, min_periods=0).max()[::-3].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

print(max_values)

0   -0.602923 
1   -0.670621
2    0.387956
3   -0.152361
```

This reason why the window size is such is that the max value for each window relates to a time frame in a test. The comparison is performed over this time frame, and `max_values` is the processed list of values. The final output of `max values` will be smaller - the comparisons shrink the processed data down.

However, the window size needs to change based on the value in the window column, and the position of the next comparison also needs to move by this variable window size (by 3, and then 2, and then 2, and then 3 again). Can I use this variable in my code to set a variable window size that moves accordingly? This would be my expected output from this:

```
0   -0.602923 = max (0,1,2)
1   -0.683756 = max (3,4)
2   -0.670621 = max (5,6)
3    0.387956 = max (7,8,9)
```

The `max_values` list will be much smaller than the original `Data` column.

I'm a bit lost as to how I would do this in a 'clean' way, that the rolling function provides when used like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact expected output?

Comment: I have added the expected output to my question

Comment: The expected output is confusing, so out of 10 rows you create only 4? Can you break down the computations?

Comment: I have tried to break down the computations and explain why the output is much smaller than the original data

Comment: Thanks but I don't see the breakdown. Can you provide it **explicitly**? (e.g. `x = max(a, b, c, d)`, `y = max(e, f, g)`)

Comment: Ah right, apologies I didn't quite understand. I've added the explicit breakdowns.

Comment: OK, so it's not really a rolling window then, you lose alignment of Window and Data and ignore all Window after the cumulated sum is > len(df). See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate a custom grouper from the first values of Window until the cumulated sum is ≥ len(df), and get the [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html):

```
group = df.index.repeat(df['Window'])[:len(df)]

out = df.groupby(group)['Data'].max()
```

Output:

```
0   -0.602923
1   -0.683756
2   -0.670621
3    0.387956
Name: Data, dtype: float64
```